# How to Design a combinational circuit using a suitable decoder and OR gate

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, decoder

I need to construct a `combinational circuit` for the below `truth table` using a `decoder` and a `OR` gate. I'm familiar with the normal procedure of drawing `combinational circuit diagrams` but got confused when I saw **"using a decoder"** part.

[image: Here's the Truth Table]

According to the `truth table` it should be a `4X16 decoder`. But How Can I mark the 16 outputs of the `decoder` with respective to the truth table's `sum of production` ??? I know how to use `OR` gate in this question, but implementing the outputs of the `decoder` is the problem.

Comment: You just don't need to implement the decoder! It's a "building block" avalilable to you ready made. You don't have to syntetize it, just use it.

Comment: Yes I know that it needs to be in Block diagrams. But I don't know how can I implement it

Comment: Why do you need to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

The decoder is a given.  It is takes 4 inputs, and has 16 outputs. Outputs could  be labeled 0 to 15. For any combination of inputs exactly one of the outputs will go high. Draw a block with 4 inputs on the left and 16 outputs on the right. That is given in the setup to the problem. For example, a 74LS154 IC is a decoder (but the outputs are active low).

The exercise is about combining the decoder and OR gates to get the output shown in the question.